# How can I display data in an Angular Material table?

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, angular-material

I have a problem when displaying list via Angular material. The content of the list does not display while the header does.
Component:

```
export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id'];
  data: Company[] = [];
  isLoadingResults = true;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getAllCompanies()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;
      console.log(this.data);
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
    });
  }

}
```

html:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-loading-shade"
       *ngIf="isLoadingResults">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table"
           matSort matSortActive="id" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Id</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Id}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

result:
[image]

list element format (json):

```
   {
        "id": 21,
        "companyName": "iErjVkVG",
        "companyDescription": "12345",
        "rating": 1,
        "companyValuation": 756,
        "salary": 3.22,
        "professionalGrowth": 2.56,
        "companyBenefits": 2.44,
        "communicationWithColleagues": 2.67,
        "educationSector": 3.11,
        "numberOfVotes": 0
    }
```

Can someone point me where I am doing wrong because it seems like the problem shouldn't appear at all
**UPDATE**
Company class:

```
export class Company {
    Id: number;
    CompanyName: string;
    CompanyDescription: string;
    Rating: number;
    CompanyValuation: number;
    Salary: number;
    ProfessionalGrowth: number;
    CompanyBenefits: number;
    CommunicationWithColleagues: number;
    EducationSector: number;
  }
```

data$ method:

```
export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id'];//, 'companyName'];

  data$: Observable<Company[]>;
  isLoadingResults = true;


  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.data$ = this.api.getAllCompanies();
    console.log(this.data$);
  }

}
```

and html:

```
 <table mat-table #table [dataSource]="data$" class="example-table"
           matSort matSortActive="id" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc">
```

Comment: Why data$ type is Observable ? Please create stackblitz example. it would be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Angular material [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api) you have to call `renderRows()` after you are changing your data array.

> If a data array is provided, the table must be notified when the array's objects are added, removed, or moved. This can be done by calling the renderRows() function which will render the diff since the last table render. If the data array reference is changed, the table will automatically trigger an update to the rows.

#### The `array` way

So either try import the MatTable and get a reference of it

```
import {MatTable} from '@angular/material';
```

Use `ViewChild` to get the table reference

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) tableReference: MatTable<Company>;

contructor(...) {}

this.api.getAllCompanies().subscribe(res => {
  this.data = res;
  this.tableReference.renderRows();
}
```

and add the `#table` reference to the table-tag like `<table mat-table #table>`. With this approach you also have to make sure that either the observable completes or that you unsubscribe from it.

#### The `observable` way

Or the (I think) better way, pass in a **dataSource** object or the observable instead of the array.

> When providing an Observable stream, the table will trigger an update automatically when the stream emits a new array of data.

```
data$: Observable<Company[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.data$ = this.api.getAllCompanies().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
    })
  );
}
```

And in your template add the `$`.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data$" ...>
```

Comment: I got the warning: Property 'renderRows' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<HTMLElement>'.  And in the second method i've done all the steps but on page I got the infinite loading

Comment: You can use the finalize operator to catch the observable complete and error events. I've updated my answer, so it sets the `isLoadingResults` flag to false properly. Import it with `import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';`.

Comment: In your updated post, the `console.log` wont show any results, because the code is asyncronous. The data arrives after you log it. You can log the data using the `tap` rxjs operator. `tap(data => console.log(data))` or `tap(console.log)` inside of the `pipe`.

Comment: @Storm updated the answer to get the *array way* working correctly without any warnings.

Comment: None of these works... In The observable way after adding finilize I still got loading and with The array way the table is still empty. Are you sure that problem lies here?

Comment: Then your observable stream does not complete. Try to replace the `finalize` operator with `tap(() => this.isLoadingResults = false)`.

Comment: You use VScode? We can use the live-share extension and I can join your programming session

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191357/discussion-between-storm-and-ngfelixl).

Comment: try to change [dataSource]="data$" 
to : [dataSource]="data$ | async" @Storm

Comment: @AmitBaranes that's removes the loading. But the table is still empty what is strange because the data is displayed in the console. I think the problem is that I can't connect the data with the table

Comment: Please provide the data you're getting. Sounds like it might be problem with that

Comment: @AmitBaranes there are 25 'companies' which structure you can see in the post (it is also visible on the Result screenshot in console)

Comment: change :  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Id}}</td> to :<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td> 
there might be case sensitive issue.

Comment: @AmitBaranes I've tried these changes with no success

Comment: Well, please provide stackblitz example.its hard to debug this without live debugging

Comment: @AmitBaranes https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrfa8b I've posted my code here, trying to configure it here